# Values of dimension with like clause SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

i want values of dimension with like clause.. i tried this

```
WITH 
SET CITY
AS
FILTER(
      [CITY].[CITY].CHILDREN,
      vbamdx!INSTR([CITY].[CITY].CURRENTMEMBER.Name,'In',1 >= 1 )
)
   MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS [CITY].[CITY].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
SELECT {[Measures].[Label]
      } ON COLUMNS , 
      [CITY].[CITY].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
FROM [TEST_Cube]
```

want All Cities with name containing "In".

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the filtered set you made.

Also, you're naming your set the same as the dimension which might give you trouble.

Try:

```
WITH 

SET FilteredCities AS
FILTER
(
    [CITY].[CITY].CHILDREN,
    vbamdx!INSTR([CITY].[CITY].CURRENTMEMBER.Name,'In',1 >= 1 )
)

MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS 
[CITY].[CITY].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 

SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[Label]
} 
ON COLUMNS , 
      FilteredCities //Use the set
ON ROWS 
FROM [TEST_Cube]
```

Comment: @Rohit Please note, that if a post answers your question, it should be marked as such. ;o)